# C# wpf how to add dynamically columns to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have DataGrid with for example 2 columns. I have a button "Open", I use it to select text files from chamber tests (files from temperatures). The number of files can be different. I want read errors (10 points) from them and show them in the data grid. One column with errors for every temperature.

I would like to add dynamically new columns for every temperature (file). I know how to do that using the name of the data grid (in file xxxxx.xaml.cs), but I would like to do that with bindings in my ViewModel.cs file.

Analyzer.xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridAnalyzer" ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridAnalyzerData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="False" 
          GridLinesVisibility="All" Width="Auto" Height="200" Margin="10" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Address" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <Label Content="{Binding Address, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <Label Content="{Binding Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<Button  Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" Content="Open"/>
```

Data binding: AnalyzerVM.cs

```cs
public class AnalyzerVM : BindableBase
{
    public DelegateCommand OpenCommand { get; set; }
    public AnalyzerVM(Action<Action> runOnUI)
    {
        OpenCommand = new DelegateCommand(OpenHandler);
    }
    private void OpenHandler()
    {
        List<string> fileNames = SelectFiles();
        GetDataOpenFile(fileNames);

    }
    ........
}
```

Comment: The decision of **displayed** columns is view related, so I don't see why you would delegate it to the viewmodel instead of writing some code in the view.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have all my code using binding so I thought everything will be that way